# Is an Incremental Approach Possible for This Case?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I'm taking data from an XML file of records that I'm using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` to deserialize into strongly-typed data structures.  Each record that I run through is getting converted to another format and written to another file.  I dislike the idea of storing the whole XML file in memory without need, but it's not critical that I conserve the memory either.  Is there a way I can rewrite to read in one record at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to read each record.  Then you can either bypass object creation and just convert the XML directly into the format you need or use the string to instatiate an [XMLTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) to read the xml.  However the XMLTextReader "Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to XML data."  So if you use it the whole XML is not in mememory, you can just use it directly, I think.